# Calling another EXE with C# on Windows fails on target machine

Tags: c#, shellexecute

I have created a Windows shell extension that provides a menu to users when they right-click in File Explorer. This then invokes a small dialogue App.

I'm a novice at software development so there is probably some schoolboy error I'm making but I just can't see it.

For testing purposes I am hard-coding the path to the EXE and ensuring it's present on the VM.

```
 private void CallExteralAddLocation(string sFullPath)
        {
            string sEXE = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "AddLocation.exe");
            WriteLog(sEXE);
            // during testing, hard-code this path
            sEXE = "C:\\temp\\AddLocation.exe";

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sEXE, sFullPath);
        }

       
        private void WriteLog(string sText)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\ShellExtLog.txt"))
            {
                sr.WriteLine(sText);
                
            }
        }
```

It works fine on my host machine but when running on a VM running Windows 10, which is where I am testing it, the dialogue App does not get invoked.

I have checked that I can invoke the **AddLocation.exe** from a command window on the VM and that works as expected. So it looks like it's just not getting called.

As it's a shell extension it's very difficult to debug. I tried using MessageBoxes and writing to the console but those wouldn't work, so I have added the WriteLog so that I have some idea of what it's doing.

This works on the host machine i.e. a log file is created and it shows the path to the EXE, but no log file is created on the VM.

NOTE: When testing on either machine, I'm installing afresh from the application's MSI. Also note that the host is running Windows 11 and the VM is running Windows 10.

So, why does the same code fail to either run the EXE or create a log file on the VM?

Comment: Permissions all good? If you install some other app that makes a change to the right click menu, like BeyondCompare or WinRar, does it work? What if you replace their EXE with yours, does it work then? If it doesn't, maybe your exe is launching but failing. If it does, maybe the setup of the registry for putting the RCM is incorrect; compare yours with theirs

Comment: Hi Caius, and thanks for the suggestions. My shell extension happens to offer 2 menu items, the 2nd one copies links to the clipboard. This works fine on the VM, so the shell extension appears to be fine, it's just that it fails to call my EXE when runniing on the VM. As mentioned above, I can manually invoke the EXE on the VM and it works as expected too. So I still appear to have two strange behaviours on the VM; (1) it doesn't invoke the EXE, and (2) the log isn't written

Comment: Wrap a try around the call to Process.start and write a log or even show a messagebox if it's UI app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually worked out that the problem was how C# handles strings.

If you read through my problem above you will see that, weirdly the same code worked fine on Windows 11 but not on Windows 10.

The problem was that I was letting the compiler interpret the path string. I had 'escaped' the slashes as shown here and it should have worked fine:

```
sEXE = "C:\\temp\\AddLocation.exe";
```

Changing it to the following resolved the problem so that it works on both now:

```
sEXE = @"C:\temp\AddLocation.exe";
```

Similarly, whereas it wouldn't create a log file on Win10, changing the path to the log file to the following fixed it:

```
    using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\ShellExtLog.txt"))
```

Comment: Hmm, no, those two are exactly equivalent. More likely, the permissions to the folder changed, or you're using a different user (or "run as admin") to run the application. Keep in mind that since about Vista, the C root defaults to read-only permissions - if you create a Temp folder (as admin), you also need to assign non-admin write permissions to it.